# caja is not mounting smb shares

Tags: mount, mate-desktop, cifs, smb, caja

Recently, caja refuses to "mount" smb locations for which it previously gave no complaint.  Usually, I would access various share points using caja by typing `smb://<server>/<share_name>` in the `Location` text-box.  When the credentials dialogue window opened, I would type my username, domain and password as appropriate for the company.  Usually, this was sufficient but no longer.

Now, I do that same process and the dialogue window immediately re-appears asking for the same information.  It simply will not take the credentials.  I can mount the same share point using `mount` from the command line, using the exact same credentials, without issue: `sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=<path/to/creds>,uid=andy //<server>/<share_name> <mount_point>`.  What might be causing this?  Oh, also, where would caja be writing its logs?  I can't find anything relevant in `dmesg` and listing the contents of `/var/log` wasn't as fruitful as I'd hoped.

Comment: @tinyfiledialogs if this is truly the answer, would you write it as an answer? I'll accept it as the answer. I'm not using Mate now so I can't verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have both of these:

```
sudo apt install gvfs-backends (some systems have it as gvfs-smb)
sudo apt install caja-share
```